# drupal 7 omega sub theme settings mark up

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-themes

Freshly installed drupal 7 and omega theme. I copied the omega-html5 to sites/all/theme folder and made changes to info file as per instructions. Then i changed the css files names. I refreshed the appearance page and my theme showed up. I enabled and set default. Alpha and Core are disabled. When i clicked the setting options, screen showed just the mark up language and nothing else.
My System is vista running Apache 2.2.16 PHP 5.3.17 and mySql 5.
What i have tried but no solution,

1. Clear the cached
2. Enabled one by one and both (Alpha and Core
   Omega theme)
3. Changed PHP memory to 128 to 256 MB
4. Previously
   tried the Omega tools to create subtheme,

Same Mark up shows when i tried setting after enabling and set default the Omega Core Theme but when i set default the Alpha theme of Omega I can see the settings. 
I really like the GUI feature of the Omega Theme and wish to use it but this problem is making me BALD(as i am pulling my hair out)
Thanks in advance,

(Just tried and found that if i use Alpha-xhtml starterkit it works fine but not sure should i use it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each subtheme must have unique configuration. For example if your subtheme's name is "**mytheme**" then you should have:

theme's folder name: mytheme
theme's info file: mytheme.info

CSS files must be set in the mytheme.info file with their names.

Also, the **base_theme** must exist on the themes folder!

Comment: Theme folder and info file names are the same,When Alpha starter kit is used no need to put CSS file names but i will give it a try and let you know, As for 'Also, the base_theme must be enabled for the subtheme to work' The hand book say dont do it, [link](http://drupal.org/node/1298670)